# LXC with both GUI apps and snapshots on unmodified Fedora kernel

Tags: linux, fedora, btrfs, lxc, snapshot

I am looking for a tool or library to run LXC that supports:

- running X applications
- conveniently snapshotting root filesystems (using a Fedora system with an unmodified kernel), so that I don't have to use lots of disk/SSD space for each root filesystem. I don't care about security.

The upstream `lxc` tools support snapshots using btrfs, but I don't think they support running X applications.

I'm not sure if libvirt supports Btrfs snapshots yet for LXC - there has been some discussion of it.

`virtenv` supports snapshots, but requires overlayfs, which is not in Fedora.

I don't think Docker supports X applications.

Correct me if I'm wrong on any of these...